# Kotlin combine more than 5 flows

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

```
inline fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6,T7,T8,T9, R> combine(
    flow: Flow<T1>,
    flow2: Flow<T2>,
    flow3: Flow<T3>,
    flow4: Flow<T4>,
    flow5: Flow<T5>,
    flow6: Flow<T6>,
    flow7: Flow<T7>,
    flow8: Flow<T8>,
    flow9: Flow<T9>,
    crossinline transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6,T7,T8,T9) -> R
): Flow<R> = combine(
    combine(flow, flow2, flow3, ::Triple),
    combine(flow4, flow5, flow6, ::Triple),
    combine(flow7, flow8, flow9, ::Triple)
) { t1, t2,t3 ->
    transform(
        t1.first,
        t1.second,
        t1.third,
        t2.first,
        t2.second,
        t2.third,
        t3.first,
        t3.second,
        t3.third
    )
}
```

```
suspend fun demoFlow() {
    val flow1 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow2 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow3 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow4 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow5 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow6 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow7 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow8 = listOf(1).asFlow()
    val flow9 = listOf(1).asFlow()

    val combinedFlow = combine(
        flow1,
        flow2,
        flow3,
        flow4,
        flow5,
        flow6,
        flow7,
        flow8,
        flow9
    ) { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9 ->
        list1 + list2 + list3 + list4 + list5 + list6 + list7 + list8 + list9
    }
    val result: List<Int> = combinedFlow.toList()
    Timber.d("$result")
}
```

I'm seeking alternative solutions to efficiently merge five Flow values into a single Flow, rather than relying on the `combine` function. In RxJava, the "Zip" operator serves a similar purpose. I would appreciate any insights you can provide regarding more optimal approaches for this scenario.

Comment: In my opinion the data layer design needs rethinking. It is hard to imagine use case when you need so many flows to combine

Comment: You're not likely to find a better option than what you have.

Comment: @Steyrix
The use case involves a RecyclerView that contains various types of views, requiring the creation of multiple flows based on the different view types. This scenario is similar to the user interface of the Google Play Store, where different views are displayed.

Comment: @Amitraj usually all the viewholders in recycler view inherit from single base interface/class so you don't need to treat them differently

Comment: @Steyrix Okay got it.